# Serialize faster in Android

Tags: java, android, serialization

Android serialization is slow. Is there some lib, that is able to serialize / deserialize faster? Without the need to write extra code in the serialized classes (eg annotations).

Comment: When you say it's slow, what are you comparing it with?

Comment: With Oracle JVM serialization.

Comment: Well, That's 2 different platforms all together. Dalvik JVM was designed specifically for mobile platforms.

Comment: Yes I know. I'm just saying that it's slow so I'm looking for a 3rd part serialization alternative.

Comment: @fhucho: You are also comparing your Oracle JVM development machine to an emulator or phone. Furthermore, serialization is impossible in the first place without "extra code in the serialized classes", let alone any theorized replacement for serialization. Serialization would be pretty close to dead last in my recommended order of data storage for any Java project, let alone Android. IMHO, use a database, or use a cross-platform file format (JSON, XML, YAML, CSV, etc.), before considering serialization.

Comment: Serialization in standard JVM is about 2 orders of magnitude faster than in Nexus One. So it's pretty slow. Perhaps the serializer could work without any extra code in the serialized classes - using reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is late but Parcelable is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Java Default Serialization?

If yes, then there is ample opportunity that you can get performance benefit by using Java Custom serialization.

Quick check if you can benefit from custom serialization
Is physical representation of data you are trying to persist similar to Logical Representation.

If answer to above question is no, then you should consider using custom serialization. 
And no matter which  framework/api you use, this rule will apply.